# Rails custom validation without raising exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails model with a `start_time` timestamp, which should obviously be in the future, which is what my validation should ensure.

appointment.rb

```
validate :start_time_in_future, :on => :create

private

def start_time_in_future
    errors.add(:base, 'Start time must be in the future') unless self.start_time > Time.now
end
```

appointments_controller.rb

```
around_filter :start_time_in_future

def create
    @appointment = Appointment.create(foo_params)
    redirect_to @appointment
end

private

def start_time_in_future
    begin
        yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
        redirect_to request.referrer, :alert => e.message
    end
end
```

And it all works just fine, but its **so** over the top. Can't I just have a custom validation that fails with a message instead of an exception?

Comment: Do you have an answer, or just hurtful sarcasm.

Comment: to be honest, i am trying to be very polite recently, but your question just took my breath. so, to be a bit more constructive here... where does that `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` come from? if you use `create` without a bang, no exception is raised. not to say that it is completely against all rails conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my fault and I feel like an idiot.

I made a class method called `.confirm!` that uses `.save!` with a bang.

If you want exceptions, use bang methods, if you don't, use `.save` and `.create()`

Comment: exactly! and sorry for the unhelpful comment.

Comment: it would be good to accept your own answer, so that others don't have to look into your question anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that by changing your `create` method like this

```
def create
   @appointment = Appointment.new(foo_params)
   if @appointment.save
       redirect_to @appointment
   else
       render "new"
   end
end
```

In your `new` template, just show error messages by retrieving it from `@appointment` object like this

```
@appointment.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: using `create` will not raise an error, only `create!` will do that.